# Converting .qgs to .shp

Tags: arcgis, data-conversion, qgis, ogr2ogr

I have a .QGS file which I'm unable to read as QGIS is not my main platform for visualising maps. Our main platform is ArcGIS. Is there any way I can convert from .QGS to .shp or .mxd?

I'm trying to use http://www.ogr2gui.ca/ to help me convert but I realised that there is no option to choose .QGS files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.qgs file is project file. It doesn't contain any layer, so is impossible to convert to shapefile. Also, is not possible to convert automatically a .qgs file to .mxd, but you can open it in a text editor and trying to replicate style, labels, etc.

Comment: I see, that's really interesting. Thank you for the reply!